# Large bootstrap stacked nav-pills?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I have a bootstrap list that is stacked like below is there a way I can make it large. Like you can with a button (btn-lg) or an input (input-lg)?

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can for example add `btn-lg` class to your `a` elements, but it will increase only font size. If you want to make it bigger as you want you have to add your own CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

`btn-lg` has following its style definition

```
.btn-lg {
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.3333333;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

In Bootstrap `line-height` for `nav-pills` is taken from within `body` selector. Thus you can redefine attribute for list-items inside `nav-pills` list this way:

```
.nav-pills>li {
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
}
.nav-pills>li>a {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

and so on

```css
.nav-pills>li {
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
}
.nav-pills>li>a {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```